# How do I build a tree of JsonNodes directly from a JsonGenerator

Tags: java, json, jackson

I already have working process that uses a `JsonGenerator` to write JSON. Now I have a need to  pass this data to another process that expects POJOs as input and produces JSON. Of course, I want to avoid building another object graph of the data that is already serialized to JSON

I was first looking at using `@JsonRawValue`, but unfortunately is doesn't work, since the annotation would need be a on a field on a class that belongs to the other process, and that cannot be changed.

However, if I pass a tree of `JsonNodes` to the other process, things will work. The problem is that the only way I can find to create a `JsonNode` tree is to parse a stream. I thought I could use my existing generator to feed a parser or another tree builder thing.

Is there such a solution? What do I miss?

Comment: There is `JsonNodeFactory` for this.

Comment: @fge Can you elaborate?

Comment: A `JsonNodeFactory` allows you to create `JsonNode` instances from scratch, of any type. But you can also serialize POJOs to JSON. It is unclear what you want exactly?

Comment: Ok, made it explicit that I want a tree of JsonNodes built directloy from the generator.

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting a little confused here... I don't use `JsonGenerator` but use `JsonNodeFactory` plenty ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to implement a `JsonGenerator` that accumulates `JsonToken`s (rather than writing directly to a byte stream), and a `JsonParser` that iterates over existing `JsonToken`s (rather than parsing them from a byte stream).

**Update:** Jackson has a class that implements this:

```
TokenBuffer t = new TokenBuffer(new ObjectMapper());
t.writeStartObject();
t.writeStringField("message", "Hello!");
t.writeEndObject();
JsonParser parser = t.asParser();
```

Comment: Agree! I've no problem implementing a JsonNode producing JsonGenerator. I'd just thought there was a solution already in place.

Comment: Just had another look, and behold! Jackson ships with a `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.TokenBuffer` class that implements `JsonGenerator` and has an `asParser()` method to get a `JsonParser`.